# openmp task for matrix addition

Tags: c++, openmp

```
void x(vector<vector<int>>&A,vector<vector<int>>&B,vector<vector<int>>&C,int n)
{
int i,j;
#pragma omp parallel
    #pragma omp single
    {
       for (i=0;i<n;++i)
         for(j=0;j<n;++j)
          #pragma omp task
           C[i][j] = A[i][j]+B[i][j];
    }
}
```

This code gives segmentation fault.

I am sure that the parallel directive will create multiple threads and then the single region will be accessed by all threads and task is created for each (i,j)th entry so n*n tasks will be created and all are independent hence there should be no race condition.

But it gives segmentation fault. Please help.

Comment: added and fixed

Comment: Still not a [mcve]. What is A, B and C? We can't test. And the indentation is also not that good.

Comment: very sorry for inconvenience, i made it better

Comment: If `n` is big, this code creates so many tasks that it can cause the runtime to run out of memory resulting in a segfault. Some runtime use throttling strategies to avoid this (and other issues as well) but AFAIK not all of them. Throttling also causes the scheduling to be less efficient in some cases... Anyway, creating a task for doing an addition is a really bad idea as creating a task has an overhead typically >200 times bigger than doing the addition and the loads/stores (assuming data fit in the L1 cache)...

Comment: If `i` and `j` are shared (likely), then you get a race condition which can typically cause a segfault. Not to mention `A`, `B` and `C` may have a bad size or be badly allocated. This is why we are asking a minimal **reproducible** example.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I am new to this forum. I will write a program that can be executed, again sorry

Comment: Ohh got it, but n is only 25 in my case

Comment: Use `for (int i=0;i<n;++i)` and `for(int j=0;j<n;++j)`, this will solve the data race.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Why do you say that there is a race condition on i and j? The loops are executed by a single thread, so no race condition can occur.

Comment: Shouldn't A, B, C be declared as `shared` in the `task` directive?

Comment: @PierU `i` and `j` are fine in the loop but they are not in the tasks. AFAIK `i` and `j` are not copied as usual because they are declared outside the parallel section so they are shared and the task construct inherit this property (otherwise, they would be firstprivate). Declaring variable close to they usage is a very good practice to avoid mistakes and also make the code easier to read.

Comment: @Charlie Still `25*25=625` tasks. THis is a lot for a code that should last for a very short time (typically 1 µs). In fact, using multiple thread will make things slower so it make no sense to use them. For a small `n` like this, you need to use OpenMP SIMD directives. In fact, mainstream compiler can optimise this loop automatically without directives. Using tasks prevent SIMD optimisations. Besides, please do not use `vector<vector<int>>` : this is not efficient. Use a flatten array instead. I advise you to read a book about high performance computing (typically including OpenMP).

Comment: @JérômeRichard OK I see, I thought they would be `firstprivate` once in the tasks

Comment: @PierU The correspontig rules can be found [here](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu103.html): " In a task generating construct, if no default clause is present, a variable for which the data-sharing attribute is not determined by the rules above and that in the enclosing context is determined to be shared by all implicit tasks bound to the current team is shared. "

Comment: Any book you can suggest for reading openmp and parallel coding?

Comment: I think "The OpenMP Common Core Making OpenMP Simple Again" is a good book to learn OpenMP, but first you should learn to write efficient (serial) C/C++ code. `vector<vector<int>>` is not an efficient way to store matrices, you should also consider using a math library. In a decent library all these matrix operations are well optimized (vectorized and parallelized).